# Transforming a summation over two indices into a summation over a single index

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

Let $R$ be a ring and $f(i,j)\in R$ for every $(i,j)\in[0,n]\times[0,m]$, where $m,n\in\mathbf{N}$. Furthermore, suppose that $f(i,j)=0$ for $i>n$ or $j>m$.

Let $0\leq k\leq n+m$. How can I prove that
$$\sum_{0\leq i\leq n\\0\leq j\leq m\\i+j=k}f(i,j)=\sum_{i=0}^kf(i,k-i)?$$

If I have two ordered sequences $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ and $(y_\beta)_{\beta\in B}$ and wish to show that their sums are equal, I usually try to prove that they are similar sequences: i.e. I try to construct an order isomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ such that
$$y_{\phi(\alpha)}=x_\alpha$$
for all $\alpha\in A$. Establishing this implies that $\sum_{\alpha\in A}x_\alpha=\sum_{\beta\in B}x_\beta$.

Let $E_k:=\{(i,j)\ |\ 0\leq i\leq n\land 0\leq j\leq m\land i+j=k\}$ for $0\leq k\leq m+n$. It is obvious that a bijection need not exist between $[0,k]$ and $E_k$. This means that demonstrating similarity between the sequences $(f(i,j))$ and $(f(i,k-i))$ is not a viable strategy.

Are there other explicit ways to prove the equality between these sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align*}
A&=\{\langle i,j\rangle:0\le i\le n,0\le j\le m,\text{ and }i+j=k\}\\
&=\{\langle i,k-i\rangle:0\le i\le n\text{ and }0\le k-i\le m\}\\
&=\{\langle i,k-i\rangle:0\le i\le n\text{ and }k-m\le i\le k\}\\
&=\big\{\langle i,k-i\rangle:\max\{0,k-m\}\le i\le\min\{n,k\}\big\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

which may be a proper subset of

$$B=\{\langle i,k-i\rangle:0\le i\le k\}\,.$$

However, if $0\le i<k-m$, then $k-i>k-(k-m)=m$, so $f(i,k-i)=0$, and if $n<i\le k$, then again $f(i,k-i)=0$, so $f(i,j)=0$ for all $\langle i,j\rangle\in B\setminus A$, and therefore

$$\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le n\\0\le j\le m\\i+j=k}}f(i,j)=\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle\in A}f(i,j)=\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle\in B}f(i,j)=\sum_{i=0}^kf(i,k-i)\,.$$

Comment: Dear Brian, I am unclear about the last step. What is the justification that allows us to pass from $\sum_{(i,j)\in B}f(i,j)$ to $\sum_{i=0}^kf(i,k-i)$?

Comment: @alf262: Because $\langle i,j\rangle\in B$ if and only if $j=k-i$ and $0\le i\le k$.

Answer (score 1):

The two sums are equal because they are finite sums and they both sum the same elements.

The sets of elements to be summed

$$ \{ f(i,j)\,\, \vert\,\,0\le i\le n, 0\le j\le m\}\text{ and }\{ f(i,k-i)\,\, \vert\,\,i\le k\le m+i\text{ while }0\le i\le n\ \}$$
are the same sets.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f(i,j)=0$ for $i>n$ or $j>m$ we get
$$\sum_{0\leq i\leq n,\\0\leq j\leq m\\\text{such that} \\i+j=k}f(i,j)= \sum_{0\leq i,\\0\leq j\\\text{such that} \\i+j=k}f(i,j) =  \sum_{0\leq i\\\text{such that}\\0\leq k-i}f(i,k-i) = \sum_{i=0}^k f(i,k-i) .$$